# React Native component is not triggering componentDidMount() after first mount

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, asyncstorage

I have two react native components, One is profile(showing logged user details) and another one for login.

In login component I set the user details to `AsyncStorage`.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

Adding user to AsyncStorage:

```
const user = {
   fname:"Tenusha",
   lname:"Guruge"
}
AsyncStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(user))
```

In the profile component I read the `AsyncStorage`

```
componentDidMount() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then(user => {
      console.log(user)
      this.setState({user})
   })
}
```

When logout I clear the `AsyncStorage`:

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem("user")
```

Problem is Once I log in and set the user details to `AsyncStorage`, it store the data and I can view them in profile component. Once user logout, the data in storage are cleared, but when I navigate to profile component the previously loaded data is still there.

I need a way to read the current `AsyncStorage` data when every time user navigate to profile component.

Comment: Are you using a StackNavigator as navigation container?

Comment: createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure a component is unmounted you can use `createSwitchNavigator`.

You can use a loginScreen as child while the other child is your `Drawer`.

When doing a logout you clear your asyncStorage and then navigate to the loginScreen and the `SwitchNavigator` will unmount your Drawer.

DrawerNavigation will keep the screens active while moving between his childs after every screens's first focus, making every componentDidMount getting triggered only at first render.

Answer (score 0):

1. Track navigation changes and clear state here
2. Consider state-manager like redux it will be cleanest approach

Comment: Are there any possible way to remount/rerender the component when navigating

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your state is not getting cleared when using `DrawerNavigator` instead you can use `stackNavigator` if you want your component to unmount when navigating out and clearing the state automatically.

Another approach can be of using state management library such as redux or flux and clear out state whenever user is logging out.